# How to close a GDAL PostGIS connection?

Tags: python, raster, postgis, gdal, connection

This issue has been bugging me for years, desperation got the better of me so now I'm here to seek the help of the public.

I'm storing raster data in a PostGIS database, and I'm using GDAL from Python to fetch data from this database. My problem (part of a bigger issue in Mapserver) is that I cannot get GDAL to release/close the database connection, unless I exit Python.

Here I set up a connection:

```
import gdal
dataset = gdal.OpenEx('PG:host=*** port=5432 user=*** password=*** dbname=*** sslmode=allow schema=*** table=***')
```

After this PostGIS shows the connection being open and idle. A plethora of places on the internet claim the correct way of closing a GDAL dataset is to set it to None: `dataset = None`. However, after I do this, PostGIS keeps showing me the connection. Once I exit Python, the connection drops. I've unsuccessfully tried combinations of different approaches to get the connection to drop:

```
dataset.FlushCache()                                                                                                                                                                                                                
gdal.Dataset.__swig_destroy__(dataset)
del dataset
```

The consequential problem I'm having is that after PostGIS reaches the client idle timeout, the connection will be dropped from the database side. After this, any attempt to open the dataset from GDAL will complain that there's no connection to the server, so I assume GDAL attempts to reuse the connection that has been cut by PostGIS.

```
dataset = gdal.OpenEx('PG:host=*** port=5432 user=*** password=*** dbname=*** sslmode=allow schema=*** table=***')
ERROR 1: Error browsing database for PostGIS Raster properties : no connection to the server
```

At this moment, the only thing I can do is exit and re-enter Python, import gdal, and then `gdal.OpenEx` is fine again.

Anything I can do to close the connection without exiting Python?

PS: I've tried to mimic the behavior using `psycopg2`, but that works as expected (connection drops from PostGIS after `.close()`):

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect('host=*** port=5432 user=*** password=*** dbname=*** sslmode=allow')
conn.close()
```

Comment: I found examples about reconnecting `pg_ds = reconnect(pg_ds, update=1)`. Could that help you?

Comment: I think you are referring to https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/a3f8f3dddfefc516c3ba86d195196d28cb673690/autotest/ogr/ogr_pg.py#L80? Unfortunately this gets me the same error, thanks though.

Comment: Right. Reconnect seems to be used about 100 times in the PG autotests so obviously developers trust that it works. But it may be that the tests are so fast that the connection is not dropped in between.

Comment: If `import gdal` works for you, how old GDAL version do you actually have? You are reading raster tables from PostGIS, right?

Comment: @user30184 Good point about the reconnect and the gdal version. To be honest the setup is slightly messy, so I spent some time on replicating. I set up a gdal (3.9) docker container, connecting to a postgis database (15.3) container. I see the same behavior, also when using a context manager (`with gdal.OpenEx(path) as ds`). I'm going to try to pull a more recent postgis version and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Reconnect does not appear in th the GDAL autotests for PostGIS raster, only in the PG vector driver tests. I think it should work in the same way but I do not know.